from long to wide format with a new variable
I have this data in long format
library(tidyverse)
n=3
set.seed(1)
d <- tibble(y=sample(0:1,n,T), 
            x1=sample(1:5,n,T),
            x2=sample(1:5,n,T),
            x3=sample(1:5,n,T))
d_long <- d |> pivot_longer(!y) 

# add new row with new variable x4
d_long_new <- q |> bind_rows(tibble(y=1,name="x4",value=10))

.
d_long_new


# A tibble: 10 x 3
       y name  value
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1     0 x1        1
 2     0 x2        3
 3     0 x3        3
 4     1 x1        2
 5     1 x2        2
 6     1 x3        1
 7     0 x1        5
 8     0 x2        3
 9     0 x3        5
10     1 x4       10

How can I convert the data to wide format to get this result?
 A tibble: 4 x 5
      y    x1    x2    x3    x4
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
1     0     1     3     3    NA
2     1     2     2     1    NA
3     0     5     3     5    NA
4     1    NA    NA    NA    10

When I try to apply the pivot_wider() function I get something other than what I expected
d_long_new |> pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)

.
# A tibble: 2 x 5
      y x1        x2        x3        x4       
  <dbl> <list>    <list>    <list>    <list>   
1     0 <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]> <NULL>   
2     1 <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]> <dbl [1]>


You need to add another column that identifies unique rows.
d_long_new |> 
  mutate(seq=row_number(), .by=name) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) # |> select(-seq)


# A tibble: 4 x 6
      y   seq    x1    x2    x3    x4
  <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     1     1     3     3    NA
2     1     2     2     2     1    NA
3     0     3     5     3     5    NA
4     1     1    NA    NA    NA    10


You can use data.table package like below
> library(data.table)

> dcast(setDT(d_long_new)[, rid := rleid(y)], rid + y ~ name)[, -1]
       y    x1    x2    x3    x4
   <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
1:     0     1     3     3    NA
2:     1     2     2     1    NA
3:     0     5     3     5    NA
4:     1    NA    NA    NA    10

